# plot to show large data points on x axis using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, heatmap

how to show variance of these data points over time? I used this plot to show them but because the time starts from 0 to 20 000 seconds and it is difficult to see all the points properly to observe the variance or invariance, the problem is: the points are overlapped to each other.
[image]
after zoom in
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the question here? How would you like the plot to look like?

Comment: I want to see all the points without zoom in

Comment: Isn't that a bit like asking how to see your house on a map of the world?

Comment: @Max Krappmann I tested your method still the same , it reduced the scale of x axis but the points are still the same

Comment: Of course the points are the same. Unless you tell how the logic of showing many very close points on a large scale should work out, there is no solution to this.

Comment: so they are overlapping do we have any solution like jitter ? or something else

Comment: There is no inbuilt "jitter" function. But of course you can calculate some new jittered coordinates yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally could solve this problem by subtracting each time from the minimum time for each subject. Now all the times starts from 0 and the variance between subjects can be seen easily [image]

Answer (score 0):

Normalize your axes to 1 by dividing with the maximum value. Afterwards you can scale your axis by a factor X.